# Fixed status bar conflicts with slide out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm making a site with a fixed status bar at the top of the page, like an iOS status bar. I want it to be fixed at the top so it's always there and content rolls under it. I also have a slide out menu that's triggered from a button on the status bar. All the site content is wrapped in a div that gets pushed to the side when the menu slides out.

My problem happens with the status bar when the menu slides out. Because it's set to `position: fixed;`, it doesn't like being moved. It pushes the status bar down the page.

My CSS for the Statusbar:

```
.toolbar {
color: purple;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding-top: 20px;
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid $white;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}
```

The JS Fiddle is a perfect example of the issue, just click the MENU button.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mqrso95g/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited based on comments:**

If you add a div inside of your nav, you can add a margin-left to that inner div when the menu is open. This jsfiddle now has the menu button still visible when the side menu opens.

I added a variable for the toolbar in `Menu.prototype._init` and used `.inner.is-active{ padding-left:300px; }` to pad the contents inside the fixed nav. You cannot add a margin or padding to the fixed element without it extending beyond the side of the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz9fqvy8/

**Original Answer**

=====================================

If you let the content hide below your slide out menu, the toolbar will stay in place. To accomplish this I removed the `translateX` from the `.site-wrap.has-push-left`.

https://jsfiddle.net/hg9038vd/

You can also replace the `translateX` with a `margin-left:300px` and the toolbar will not push down.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5xcq3zf/

Comment: Thanks for the help! I know sliding OVER the content is an option, but I'm really wanting to push the content over.  Although the second solution does keep the status bar in place, it doesn't seem to actually move it over, or at least move over the buttons. See this update:   https://jsfiddle.net/m5xcq3zf/1/        I would like the MENU button to slide over and still be visible when the menu is popped out (and the App text to be slide off the page, as if it were moving over the entire Status bar out of view).  Is there a way to accomplish that?a

Comment: Figured that last part out. I just had to change `left: 0;` to `margin: 0;` and now everything is fluid and looks great! I'm still marking your answer as correct, I just needed to make one small change to get the exact result I wanted.  Final Fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/m5xcq3zf/2/

Comment: One last note. If you want all your content to stay the exact same, and not got reformatted by the `margin-left: 300;` change, you must add `#site-wrap { width:100%; }` earlier in the CSS so it doesn't get resized.